# Android, Active wifi scanning

Tags: android, wifi, rssi

I have seen a lot of topics on this question, but they all go back few years so let's try this again!

For my thesis I'm trying to program indoor localisation based on RSSI obtained from APs. I'm using a oneplus two and when scanning for RSSI values, using WifiManager.startScan() combined with a listener to fetch the results when ready, If find that the scan is really, really slow and not suited for live support.

Is there a way to speed this process up? Active scanning? Scanning only a certain band/freq? I can't find a solution to the problem, so I'm asking your help!

Answer (score 0):

An example about wifi scanning:

```
package com.android.wifitester;

import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.<span class="hilite">wifi</span>.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WifiTester extends Activity {
TextView mainText;
WifiManager mainWifi;
WifiReceiver receiverWifi;
List<ScanResult> wifiList;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);
mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
mainWifi.startScan();
mainText.setText("\\nStarting Scan...\\n");
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Refresh");
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
mainWifi.startScan();
mainText.setText("Starting Scan");
return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}

protected void onPause() {
unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);
super.onPause();
}

protected void onResume() {
registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
super.onResume();
}

class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
sb = new StringBuilder();
wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++){
sb.append(new Integer(i+1).toString() + ".");
sb.append((wifiList.get(i)).toString());
sb.append("\\n");
}
mainText.setText(sb);
}
}
}
```

Comment: That's indeed the way I'm doing it right now, but this is a passive scan and is quite slow :s